# Updating Progress bar from another class

Tags: java, javafx, concurrency, progress-bar

I am writing a code that reads considerably large arxml file and stores data from it. I have a main class ARXMLParser and a class called ParsedDatabase. I am calling a function from main loadFromArxml and passing the path of file as parameter. The function would read and store that data. I want to update Progress bar in main as the function loadFromArxml is reading data.

I am using class Task and performing my function in it. However I don't know how would I update progress from it.

This is my main code

```
import java.io.File;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import parser.ParsedDatabase;

public class ARXMLParser extends Application {
    private ProgressBar progress;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TextField arxmlPath = new TextField("");
        arxmlPath.setEditable(false);
        arxmlPath.setFocusTraversable(false);
        arxmlPath.setPromptText("ARXMl File");

        Label arxmlLbl = new Label("No File Selected");

        Button btnArxml = new Button("Browse");
        btnArxml.setOnAction(e -> {
            FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
            chooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
            FileChooser.ExtensionFilter fileExtensions = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("ARXML Files (*.arxml)",
                    "*.arxml");
            chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(fileExtensions);
            File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            if (file != null) {
                arxmlPath.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                arxmlLbl.setText(file.getName());
            }
        });

        HBox arxmlHbox = new HBox();
        arxmlHbox.setSpacing(10);
        arxmlHbox.getChildren().addAll(arxmlPath, btnArxml);
        HBox.setHgrow(arxmlPath, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox.setHgrow(btnArxml, Priority.ALWAYS);

        progress = new ProgressBar();
        progress.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        Button btnParse = new Button("Parse");
        btnParse.setOnAction(e -> {
            ParsedDatabase parsedDatabase = new ParsedDatabase();
            if (!arxmlPath.getText().isEmpty()) {
                Task<Void> parse = new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        // Function that reads the file
                        parsedDatabase.loadFromArxml(arxmlPath.getText());
                        return null;
                    }
                };

                progress.progressProperty().bind(parse.progressProperty());
                Thread thread = new Thread(parse);
                thread.setDaemon(true);
                thread.start();
            }
        });

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setFillWidth(true);
        vBox.setSpacing(15);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(arxmlHbox, arxmlLbl, btnParse, progress);
        vBox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 10, 15, 10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 500, 170);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ARXML Parser");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void setProgressBar(Double value) {
        progress.setProgress(value);
    }

    public double getProgress() {
        return progress.getProgress();
    }
}
```

And my ParsedDatabase class

```
package parser;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParsedDatabase {

    public void loadFromArxml(String arxmlPath) throws Exception {

        File file = new File(arxmlPath);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scan.nextLine());
            // Update progress based on file length
        }
        scan.close();
        // Update progress 
        exportToExcel();
        // Update progress
    }

    public void exportToExcel() {
        // Export to excel
       // Update progress
    }
}
```

I was wondering how to update progress from the method. I do know there is a way I can do it. That is if I call both functions from main and from there updating progress is easy. Something like this

```
updateProgress(0, 1.0);
parsedDatabase.loadFromArxml(arxmlPath.getText());
updateProgress(0.5, 1.0);
parsedDatabase.exportToExcel();
updateProgress(1, 1.0);
```

However, The progress bar then will not progress smoothly but will go from 0 to 50 and to 100. I want it to be continuous. If there is a better way to achieve the same thing please let me know. This isn't an assignment. I am just learning concurrency at my own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Platform.runLater and Task in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13784333/platform-runlater-and-task-in-javafx)

Comment: In most of the example people are performing the task in main and update it from there. I do not want to perform in the main. I don't know if it is something I should even do.

Comment: The code from `loadFromArxml()` should be your `Task`'s `call()` method. Then  you update the progress from within the `call()` method.

Comment: Check out this link [Javafx Task - update progress from a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357005/javafx-task-update-progress-from-a-method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to have the code that you are running in `loadFromArxml()` be moved to the `Task`'s `call()` method.

Then you can update the progress from within the actual working method. Then just bind your `ProgressBar` as usual.

Here is a complete example to demonstrate, with `loadFromArxml()` in a separate class.

> **ProgressTaskExample.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProgressTaskExample extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // The ProgressBar
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(0.0);

        // Button to start the task
        Button button = new Button("Run Task");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {

            System.out.println("Starting task ...");

            // Get the loading Task
            final Task<Void> task = Datasource.loadFromArxml();

            // Catch any exceptions
            task.setOnFailed(wse -> {
                System.out.println("Error");
                task.getException().printStackTrace();
            });

            // Print success when complete
            task.setOnSucceeded(wse -> {
                System.out.println("DONE!");
                progressBar.setStyle("-fx-accent: #19ee15");
            });

            // Bind our ProgressBar's properties
            progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

            // Run the task
            new Thread(task).start();

        });

        // Add our nodes to the scene
        root.getChildren().addAll(button, progressBar);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

> **Datasource.java:**

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Datasource {

    public static Task<Void> loadFromArxml() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                // Do your processing here

                updateProgress(0, 100);

                // Run for 5 seconds
                int i = 0;
                while (i < 100) {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    i++;

                    updateProgress(i, 100);
                }

                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of moving the `Task` to my other class. It makes sense now. Thank You.